# ArrayList cannot be converted to boolean

Tags: java

**Quiero insertar usuario-contraseña y comprobar si existe en la base de datos.** Si coincide, me llega al archivo Index.java, si no coincide, mensaje de error y volver a intentarlo.

El error lo tengo en la línea:

```
} else if(Conexiones.cargar_administradores(usuario, password)) { //aquí error
```

Error:

```
ArrayList cannot be converted to boolean
```

Tengo una tabla en **MySQL/SQL** creada de la siguiente manera:

```
CREATE TABLE administradores (
    usuario VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    password VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO administradores (usuario, password) VALUES 
("ADMIN", "ADMIN"),
("USUARIO1", "USUARIO1");
```

**función cargar_administradores(String usuario, String password):**

```
   public static ArrayList cargar_administradores(String usuario, String password) {
        ArrayList<Administrador> administradores = new ArrayList<Administrador>();
        String bbdd = Conexiones.bbdd;
        Connection c = (Connection) Conexiones.conexion_a_BBDD(bbdd);
        Statement stm;
        ResultSet rs;
        try {
            stm = c.createStatement();
            String consulta_clientes = "SELECT * FROM administradores;";
            rs = stm.executeQuery(consulta_clientes);
            //System.out.println("CONSULTA TODOS LOS ADMINISTRADORES: ");
            while (rs.next()) {
                Administrador administrador = new Administrador();
                administrador.setUsuario(rs.getString("usuario")); 
                administrador.setPassword(rs.getString("password")); 
                administradores.add(administrador);  
            }
            c.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for(int i=0;i<administradores.size();i++){
            System.out.println(administradores.get(i));
        }      
        return administradores;
    }
```

**función button_acceder -comprobar-:**

```
   private void button_accederActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
        String usuario = textfield_usuario.getText();
        String password = textfield_password.getText();

        if(Conexiones.conexion_a_BBDD("agenda") == null){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡MySQL failed!", "ADMINISTRADOR", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            this.dispose();
        } else if(Conexiones.cargar_administradores(usuario, password)) { //aquí error
            Conexiones.cargar_administradores(usuario, password);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡Bienvenido '"+usuario+"'!", "ADMINISTRADOR", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            Index i = new Index();
            i.setVisible(true);
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡No existe este administrador en la base de datos!", "ADMINISTRADOR", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            textfield_usuario.requestFocus();
        }
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El mensaje no puede ser más claro (aparte de que está en inglés). Dentro de un *if* has de tener una expresión que devuelva un boolean, pero tu expresión es una llamada al método "cargar_administradores" que devuelve un ArrayList.

Comment: ¿Alguna forma de solucionarlo? ¿Cómo puedo saber si encontró al usuario con la clave asociada correctamente o no?

Comment: ¿Pero ese inicio de sesión es para administradores? ¿Dónde está para los usuarios finales?

Comment: @MrDave1999 Si de momento sólo para administradores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como te comenta SJuan76, estas validando en el if una función que te retorna un ArrayList y no de tipo boolean, lo que puedes hacer, es obtener el tamaño de tu ArrayList y si es mayor de 0 dar el ingreso.

El código debería quedar de la siguiente forma:

```
} else if(Conexiones.cargar_administradores(usuario, password).size() > 0) {
```

Para validar el usuario debes cambiar tu sql de consulta, quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
String consulta_clientes = "SELECT * FROM administradores WHERE usuario = '" + usuario + "' AND password = '" + password + "'";
```

Esto es siempre y cuando quieras validar el usuario contra la BBDD.

Comment: En todas las combinaciones me dice Bienvenido... cuando en realidad es inválido.

Comment: eso es por tu query de validación, te edito la respuesta.

Comment: esa consulta la tengo realizada como puedes ver en mi pregunta, pero lo que me falla es el .size()>0

Comment: En tu consulta te traes todos los usuarios y te indico que valides uno en especifico, si lo que deseas es validar que el usuario este dentro del arrayList, debes hacer como te indico @carles en su primer ejemplo de código.

Comment: Si modificas el else if por el que te comente y modificas la consulta a la base de datos por la del ejemplo debería funcionar sin problemas.

Comment: Respecto a tu ejemplo, compila perfectamente pero seguidamente me da un error: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'a' in 'where clause'

Comment: me faltaron unas comillas simples, voy a editar la respuesta. Pero basicamente antes del igual debes añadir ' y cerrar despues de la variable.

Answer (score 1):

La función cargar_administradores devuelve un ArrayList, y por tanto no se puede usar en un if. Eso es lo que te está diciendo.

Lo solucionas diciendo en la cabecera de la función  que devuelve un booleano, no un ArrayList.  Y en la última linea, en lugar de return administradores, pones que retorne si la lista contiene los valores recibidos como parámetro. Más o menos así.

```
   public static boolean cargar_administradores(String usuario, String 
            password) {
        ArrayList<Administrador> administradores = new ArrayList<Administrador>();
        String bbdd = Conexiones.bbdd;
        Connection c = (Connection) Conexiones.conexion_a_BBDD(bbdd);
        Statement stm;
        ResultSet rs;
        try {
           stm = c.createStatement();
           String consulta_clientes = "SELECT * FROM administradores;";
           rs = stm.executeQuery(consulta_clientes);
           //System.out.println("CONSULTA TODOS LOS ADMINISTRADORES: ");
           while (rs.next()) {
    //
    // Este codigo es poco conciso, deberías tener un constructor 
    // en Administrador(String u, String p) para abreviar aqui
    //
               Administrador administrador = new Administrador();
               administrador.setUsuario(rs.getString("usuario")); 
               administrador.setPassword(rs.getString("password")); 
               administradores.add(administrador);  
           }
           c.close();
        } 
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Puedes ahorrarte este for poniendo el print en el while de arriba
        for(int i=0;i<administradores.size();i++){
            System.out.println(administradores.get(i));
        }      
        return administradores.contains(new administrador(usuario,password));
}
```

Pero ya puestos, si lo único que pretendes en esa función es verificar la existencia de ese usuario, podrías prescindir del arraylist, y en el bucle hacer la comparación de ambos campos devolviendo true desde dentro del bucle si se da el caso.

Es decir,

```
   public static boolean cargar_administradores(String u, String p) {
        String bbdd = Conexiones.bbdd;
        Connection c = (Connection) Conexiones.conexion_a_BBDD(bbdd);
        try {
           Statement stm = c.createStatement();
           String sql = "SELECT * FROM administradores;";
           ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery(sql);
           //System.out.println("CONSULTA TODOS LOS ADMINISTRADORES: ");
           String dbu;
           String dbp;
           while (rs.next()) {
               dbu = rs.getString("usuario");
               dbp = rs.getString("password");
               if (u.equals(dbu) && p.equals(dbp)) break;
           }
           c.close();
           return u.equals(dbu) && p.equals(dbp);
        } 
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
   }
```

Pero este código así, tardarà el doble de tiempo cuando el número de usuarios crezca al doble de lo que haya.

Por ello, mejor sería dejar la verificación en manos del DBMS, puesto que él lo hará en log(n). que es infinitamente más rápido. Es decir, cambiar la query y poner:
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM administradores WHERE usuario = '" + usuario + "' AND password = '" + password + "'";

Haciendolo así, y anañizando si devuelve nulo o una respuesta, tardará mucho menos, aunque eso no se notará hasta que haya muchos usuarios.

Fijate también que para las queries incrustadas en código no hace falta el punto y coma final.

Espero que sirva.

Comment: ¿Alguna solución respecto a mi código? Opto mejor por la opción de comprobar la existencia de un usuario con la password asociada.

Comment: En el primer código me da error la línea: return administradores.contains(new administrador(usuario,password)); y sí, tengo un constructor en la clase Administrador

Comment: Me sigue sin funcionar...

Answer (score 0):

Como te comentan en otras respuestas, es porque estas intentando usar un ArrayList en una condicion.

```
} else if(!Conexiones.cargar_administradores(usuario, password).isEmpty()) {
```

Espero que te sirva.